The response to the first HTTP request in a TCP session takes much longer with Solr 9.x
After we updated to Solr 9.x, we noticed that the first get/post request on a new TCP session takes much longer compared to older versions of Solr (we tested Solr 6.x and 8.x) - but only if this first request is sent via a proxy.
See this Example.
The first two lines show a direct request / response.
The last two lines show the same request but this time via a proxy.
The logging in Solr does not show anything suspicious.
First we assumed it has something to do with the embedded jetty version (got updated from jetty 9.x to 10.x in Solr 9.2) but Solr 9.0/9.1 also show this unexpected delay.
Does anyone have an idea where to start searching?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Look at what the difference is between the proxy <-> solr request and the request without the proxy present; could be that the proxy uses HTTP/2, QUIC etc. to the upstream server, or adds a keep-alive that the client doesn't expect.

Issue is solved in the meantime. Problem was that Solr 9.x runs with the Java security manager enabled by default. That causes a delay of the first request (only if the request is originated from another subnet). There were no delays anymore after we set this parameter to false (SOLR_SECURITY_MANAGER_ENABLED=false).
